# Translate a boolean value to show yes/no in a dataformwebpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part, xslt, data-form-web-part

I have a dataformwebpart which gets data from a SharePoint list. I am trying to show a yes/no field in the webpart but it displays 1 for yes and 0 for a no. I would like it to displayed yes and no instead of the numbers. I have tried the translate function but it did not help me. Can someone let me know which function should I add in the below code

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open the page with the DFWP on it in SPD.  Look for the XSL that is controling that column and change the set value from 1 or 0 to yes or no.  You could also try putting a custom filter on you DFWP in SPD that could do the same thing as well.